# Dom Crash react select option

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

React DOM stops working when `<option>` contains three interpolated value if one is a conditional.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0opjvycp/

Changing the value of the `<select>` crashes with `NotFoundError: Node was not found`

It's working fine on React 15, this only happens in react 16.2

Comment: Not sure about React 15 version, but i felt you are changing the object structure in your onchange. (Not sure if that was intended) 
updated fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/0opjvycp/1/

Comment: Thanks I think this is the way to turn around this error.

Comment: Could be. still wondering how it worked in React15.
Anyways. hope it solved your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a weird one.

If I replace your `{isSelected && '(Y) '}` with {`isSelected ? '(Y) ' : ''`} there's no problem.  But in the latter case, the output is always a string.

It seems that React is unhappy re-rendering if you're changing `<Option>`'s  children between `false` and string values.  Maybe there's a new bug in DOM reconciliation.

Additionally, if your intent is to reset the store and select a single option for the menu on a change event, instead of doing:

```
this.setState({ 
              items: {
                      ...this.state.items,
                     [v]: true
                     }
              })
```

do something like:

```
this.setState({ 
              items: {
                      ...{a:false, b:false},
                     [v]: true
                     }
              })
```

As written, you never unselect an option.

Comment: Actually I downgraded to 15.6 version. Your solution is right but not practical. If I have a lot of options,I would have a lot of duplicated code. +1 for the answer though

Comment: Hm, not quite sure I understand your point about economy of code.  Strictly speaking, the content of an `<option>` should be a single string.  You're producing three unkeyed child nodes, some of which are strings and some are booleans.  If you actually build a single string, it would be guaranteed to work.  I'm not sure if I expect well-defined behavior as written.  If you are concerned about my setState suggestion, why don't you just store the single selected value in state (this.state.selected) and keep an `const` object with all if list options to populate the list - pass it in as a prop?